# Rotating Earth around Sun

Tags: javascript, html, math, three.js

I am trying to make 3D Solar system so first I created the Sun and Earth with THREE.SphereGeometry()

```
var sphere2 = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(50, 100, 100),
new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({side: THREE.DoubleSide, map:txt2}));
sphere2.position.set(100,5,30);
```

sphere2 is Earth and I would like to rotate it around the Sun, in my `render()` I added

```
  sphere2.position.x -= 1;
  sphere2.position.normalize();
  sphere2.position.multiplyScalar( 200 );
```

I think I only need to edit the position of x axis, right? But this makes only half rotation, from what I see. I obviously need to stop the subtraction after sometime and increase the x position but this would only make the Earth go backwards, it wouldn't go behind the Sun, it always makes a half circle and stops, finally the value of x position is "-200" I was expecting to find it "-100" but don't know why. I also would like to give Earth an axial tilt of 23.5 degrees, I tried with `quaternion = new THREE.Quaternion().setFromAxisAngle( axisOfRotation, angleOfRotation );` but didn't work. I would be glad if you can give me hand!

Comment: _"I think I only need to edit the position of x axis, right?"_ I don't think that will work. At some point, the Earth's position will lie on top of the x axis, at which point subtracting 1 and normalizing won't change its position at all. You should consider coming up with a different strategy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest (though not scientifically accurate) thing to do would to use Math.cos/sin paired with an updating angle value. Something like this in the frame update:

```
earthOrbitAngle += earthOrbitSpeed; //advance angle in degrees
var orbitAngleInRadians = earthOrbitAngle * Math.PI / 180; //convert to radians

//update position of earth...
earth.position.x = Math.cos(orbitAngleInRadians) * earthOrbitRadius; 
earth.position.z = Math.sin(orbitAngleInRadians) * earthOrbitRadius;
```

You could elongate either the x or z value to make the orbit elliptical by multiplying earthOrbitRadius by some factor.

You could tilt the earth just by setting it's rotation.z. However, if you want to have the Moon and have it orbit around the tilted axis, then easiest thing to do is create an empty Object3D container to hold the two, with the moon running its own orbiting script. Then you animate that container around the Sun. So the set up would look something like this:

```
theSun = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(30, 16, 15), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: 'yellow' 
}));
scene.add(theSun);

theEarthAndMoon = new THREE.Object3D();
theEarthAndMoon.rotation.z = 23.439281 * Math.PI / 180; //tilt of earth in radians;
scene.add(theEarthAndMoon);

theEarth = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(5, 16, 15),  new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
    color:"blue"
}));

theEarthAndMoon.add(theEarth); 

theMoon = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(1, 16, 15),  new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
    color:"white"
}));

theEarthAndMoon.add(theMoon);
```

And in the frame update:

```
//run the earth's orbit around the Sun
earthOrbitAngle += earthOrbitSpeed; 
var radians = earthOrbitAngle * Math.PI / 180;

theEarthAndMoon.position.x = Math.cos(radians) * earthOrbitRadius;
theEarthAndMoon.position.z = Math.sin(radians) * earthOrbitRadius;

//run the Moon's orbit around the Earth
moonOrbitAngle += moonOrbitSpeed; 
var moonRadians = moonOrbitAngle * Math.PI / 180;

theMoon.position.x = Math.cos(moonRadians) * moonOrbitRadius;
theMoon.position.z = Math.sin(moonRadians) * moonOrbitRadius;
```

You can see it running here: [Simple Sun, Earth, and Moon at JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qn7cL/3/)

Now, if you want to go deep down the rabbit hole of accurate orbiting mechanics, I would suggest starting with looking under the hood of this incredible Three.js simulation of all the planets and 600,000 asteroids: [Asterank project](http://www.asterank.com/)

Comment: Dear Matthew I thank you very much for putting a lot of effort and giving the right solution, I wished you showed up a little before :) but nevertheless Im glad you started to answer questions and chose my question as first :) I found the same answer with tons of googling, copied from a working solar system : `earth.position.set(200* Math.cos(e_angleEARTH), 200* Math.sin(e_angleEARTH), 0);` This is the solution I came up with, same thing sin/cos. Next thing to make my 3D Solar system more realistic I would like to make the orbits "oval" on the example you gave they are also circular.Any hints?

Comment: Thanks @Anarkie, it was my pleasure. As for you follow up question, modifying the above example, you can elongate out one of the axis by tacking on a modifier:

`var elongatedFactor = 1.5;
theEarthAndMoon.position.x = Math.cos(radians) * earthOrbitRadius * elongatedFactor;
theEarthAndMoon.position.z = Math.sin(radians) * earthOrbitRadius;`

That would make the distance traveled on the x-axis 1.5 times as long as the z axis.